# How can I make a field in a table reference an entire other table? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

What I'm aiming to do is have a table of teams and then each team has a reference to its table of players. So for example if team A has players x, y, and z, I can reference all of them from team A's entry in the table. The teams have a variable size from 8-12.

Sort of what I have right now is:

```
CREATE TABLE team_a_players(
    PlayerName varchar(255),
    PlayerELO int
);

CREATE TABLE teams(
    TeamName varchar(255),
    TeamELO int,
    TeamRank int
);
```

I want to be able to reference the team players from the teams entry in their players table.

Another approach I was considering was to have just 2 tables, one for all teams and one for all players and have the players table have a foreign key associated with the team that player belongs to. I'm ok doing it either way however.

Comment: Hello. It doesn't make much sense to create a new table each time you add a new team. Create a table called `players` and add a field `team_id` that references the `id` of the `team` table with a foreign key.

Comment: Each table should have an auto-incrementing integer primary key column. I use int(11) type for that column. As @solarc said, there should also be a column in the players table that references the key of the teams table. One more thing to consider, if it's possible for a player to appear on more than one team (different league, different sport), then you would need to setup a many-to-many relationship with a third, linking table. If that's a possibility, I can show you how that would be done.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Referencing a team from a player seems to be the easier solution. Each player will only have a single team so that should be ok!

Comment: @JashanjotDhilon this is called Database Normalization, you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)